# Python: add a value to the end of the inner-most right nested list

Tags: python, list, recursion

What I'm trying to do, is, given a list with an arbitrary number of other nested lists, recursively descend through the last value in the nested lists until I've reached the maximum depth, and then append a value to that list. An example might make this clearer:

```
>>> nested_list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
>>> last_inner_append(nested_list1, 7)
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7]]

>>> nested_list2 = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6]
>>> last_inner_append(nested_list2, 7)
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6, 7]
```

The following code works, but it seems excessively tricky to me:

```
def add_to_inner_last(nested, item):
    nest_levels = [nested]
    try:
        nest_levels.append(nested[-1])
    except IndexError:                    # The empty list case
        nested.append(item)
        return
    while type(nest_levels[-1]) == list:
        try:
            nest_levels.append(nest_levels[-1][-1])
        except IndexError:                 # The empty inner list case
            nest_levels[-1].append(item)
            return
    nest_levels[-2].append(item)
    return
```

Some things I like about it:

- It works
- It handles the cases of strings at the end of lists, and the cases of empty lists

Some things I don't like about it:

- I have to check the type of objects, because strings are also indexable
- The indexing system feels too magical--I won't be able to understand this tomorrow
- It feels excessively clever to use the fact that appending to a referenced list affects all references

Some general questions I have about it:

- At first I was worried that appending to `nest_levels` was space inefficient, but then I realized that this is probably just a reference, and a new object is not created, right?
- This code is purely side effect producing (It always returns `None`). Should I be concerned about that?

Basically, while this code works (I think...), I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. By better I mean clearer or more pythonic. Potentially something with more explicit recursion? I had trouble defining a stopping point or a way to do this without producing side effects.

**Edit:**

To be clear, this method also needs to handle:

```
>>> last_inner_append([1,[2,[3,[4]]]], 5)
[1,[2,[3,[4,5]]]]
```

and:

```
>>> last_inner_append([1,[2,[3,[4,[]]]]], 5)
[1,[2,[3,[4,[5]]]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
def last_inner_append(x, y):
    try:
        if isinstance(x[-1], list):
            last_inner_append(x[-1], y)
            return x
    except IndexError:
        pass
    x.append(y)
    return x
```

Comment: Btw, a small suggestion (kinda holywar stuff): one should use 'isinstance' in case of inheritance, and type(obj) in case of checking object's type.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't handle the cases where x is an empty list, or the last inner most list is an empty list...

Comment: But, if you wrap the whole thing in a `try:` `except IndexError:` block it works fine. If you edit this to include that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This function returns the deepest inner list:

```
def get_deepest_list(lst, depth = 0):
    deepest_list = lst
    max_depth = depth

    for li in lst:
        if type(li) == list:
            tmp_deepest_list, tmp_max_depth = get_deepest_list(li, depth + 1)
            if max_depth < tmp_max_depth: # change to <= to get the rightmost inner list
                max_depth = tmp_max_depth
                deepest_list = tmp_deepest_list

    return deepest_list, max_depth
```

And then use it as:

```
def add_to_deepest_inner(lst, item):
    inner_lst, depth = get_deepest_list(lst)
    inner_lst.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

```
def last_inner_append(cont, el):
    if type(cont) == list:
        if not len(cont) or type(cont[-1]) != list:
            cont.append(el)
        else:
            last_inner_append(cont[-1], el)
```

- I think it's nice and clear, and passes all your tests.
- It is also pure side-effect; if you want to change this, I suggest you go with BasicWolf's approach and create a 'selector' and an 'update' function, where the latter uses the former.
- It's the same recursion scheme as Phil H's, but handles empty lists.
- I don't think there is a good way around the two type tests, however you approach them (e.g. with 'type' or checking for 'append'...).

Answer (score 0):

You can test if `append` is callable, rather than using try/catch, and recursing:

```
def add_to_inner_last(nested, item):
    if callable(nested,append):
        if callable(nested[-1],append):
            return add_to_inner_last(nested[-1],item)
        else:
            nested.append(item)
            return true
    else:
        return false
```

It's slightly annoying to have to have two `callable` tests, but the alternative is to pass a reference to the parent as well as the child.

Answer (score 0):

```
def last_inner_append(sequence, element):
    def helper(tmp, seq, elem=element):
        if type(seq) != list:
            tmp.append(elem)
        elif len(seq):
            helper(seq, seq[-1])
        else:
            seq.append(elem)
    helper(sequence, sequence)
```